# git rebase merge conflict in an un-related commit?

Tags: git, rebase

I have a stack of local commits, say, `a, b, c` from old to most recent.
I did a `git pull --rebase origin master` and it resulted in a merge conflict. When I did `git log`, it showed that the top most commit is `a`, but the merge conflict is relevant for files affected in commit `b`. I am not sure if I understand how rebasing works properly, but shouldn't `git log` show `b` as the top commit since that's the commit we need to resolve the merge conflict in, so that we can then `git commit --amend` and subsequently `git rebase --continue`?

Comment: git stops before applying `b` because of the conflict, that's why the log shows `a` as the last made commit - `b` hasn't been sucessfully commited yet. `git status` will show you which files have conflicts and markers in the files will show you where the conflicts are

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/addressing-merge-conflicts/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line

Comment: @fredrik Ahh I see, so I think this is related to a separate question I had but let me ask that first. After you resolve the merge conflicts, are you supposed to `git commit --amend`? Based on your link, it seems I should be doing that, but that would amend `a`. So I think I shouldn't amend, and I should do `git rebase --continue`? Will it automatically put those changes in `b` when I `git rebase --continue`?

Comment: @roulette01 : no need for `--amend`. After fixing the conflicts, run `git rebase --continue`. `git commit --amend` would merge `a` and `b` together.